# Why the button doesn't work in SwiftUI when it is located in some condition

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why the button doesn't work in this code by using SwiftUI?
I can't click the button.

When I lay the button on the top in VStack, it can work.
But when it is in below code, it can't work properly.

Is this related to VStack, TabView or button's overlay?

I think it is caused by button's offset and padding & tabview's padding.
Can I change it to ZStack in all same layout?
Please tell me how to do.
Thank you.

```
struct Profile: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                 
                    Spacer()
                }
               
               
                HStack{
                    Text("|")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                   
                        Image(systemName: "birthday.cake")
                            
                        Text("birthDay")
                            
                }
                
            }
            .frame(height: 300)
            .padding(.bottom,50)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("hello")
            }){
                Text("edit")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 48)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.red))
                    .background(Color(.white))
                    .cornerRadius(24)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24)
                            .stroke(Color(.red), lineWidth: 1.0)
                    )
                    .offset(y: -35)
                    .padding(.bottom, -20)
                    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)) 
            }
            

            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text("note")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)     
                VStack{
                    Text("phone")                             
                }
                .tag(1)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            .frame(height:200)
            .padding(.top,-60)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely it's because `.padding(.top,-60)` overlaps your button and "steals" taps from it. Try to remove that line and see if it's working. Generally specifying layout like this (with absolute numbers, and negatives on top of it) is a bad idea, so try to find relative ways to define such relation

Comment: Hi, flatasearth. Thank you for your good advices. It worked!! 
So do you mean I should not use the exact absolute number even in frame? 
Please teach me to do. Thank you.

Comment: @ShunTakanashi because the phone / iPads can have different sizes, and also user may use them vertically _or_ horizontally, if you hard-code numbers, they may not look good for all the devices. So it's better to use relative sizes, such as "third of the screen height" or "middle of the screen" instead of giving exact numbers. Check out the `GeometryReader` - that can help a lot in cases where you need to achieve a specific look. Here's a good walkthrough: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader

Answer (score 3):

The padding
**.padding(.top,-60)**
is covering your button.
Add the below line just after the padding, you'll see tabview covering the button with green transparent background.
**.background(Color.green.opacity(0.4))**

Just remove the **.padding(.top,-60)** and the button will click.

Comment: Great !! Its work like charm

Answer (score -2):

Add "Spacer()" underneath the Button

```
Spacer()
```

Spacer between Button() and Tabview() will enable the button to be clickable.

[image]